# how do i load plugin from sdf model in ros

Tags: ros

Similarly like i can put a plugin in urdf file and than when i launch that urdf in gazebo i can control that robot, isn't their any way how i can contol the robot model. I tried to use this line in my launch file but its not working:`<param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find <my_robot>)/model.sdf"/>`

So is their any way how i can use the plugin from sdf robot to my gazebo ros control package or robot_description src file similarly like i did with urdf file. Like when i launchdd the urdf file with plugins in them, i can communicate with the robot from my plugin file than use ros control. Similarly i loaded the sdf robot in my world file than when i launchd it from my roslaunch file the plugin is not loaded. Why i want to do this was, because so many robot models like r2, kuka and others where present in sdf format so i want to communicate them from my ros package. I am using ros indigo and gazebo 7.4 for robot simulation.
Why is this happening that when i spawn a urdf robot in gazebo i'm able to communicate it through ros but not when i spawn a sdf robot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) reads:

> Under the hood, Gazebo will then convert the URDF to SDF automatically.

Thus, I suggest the problem is in the way you run your sdf, nothing to do with sdf or urdf. Have you tried running the sdf directly (like rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo /path/to/your/sdf)? Not sure about indigo, it helped with kinetic.